# removing specific customview,uiview,textview,etc from viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

what i am trying to do is simple. let me explain what i have first, in the mainviewcontroller i have 3 main view at the beginning navbar, content,and bottombtn. i have a sidebar btn that then trigger a function in the mainviewcontroller, each function is suppose to remove the middle view (the content) and then place a new subview to take the content place.

the problem: it work at first the function delete contentTxt and replace it with one of the new view example: connectView, but the problem is when i try to trigger another function let say addAchievementView() it will not delete connectView and then add achievementview instead it let add achievementview below the connect View

my Goal: is for the function to delete the previous view(whichever view that is taking the contentplace) and then adding a new view. is there a way to get around this? or is there a better way to do this?

here is the mainViewController code:

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController {

    let navbar:navbarView = {
       let content = navbarView()
        return content
    }()

    let contentTxt:UITextView = {
       let content = UITextView()
        content.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        content.font = UIFont(name: "copperplate", size: 20)
        return content
    }()

    let bottomBtn:UIButton = {
       let content = UIButton()
        content.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return content
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentTxt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(navbar)
        view.addSubview(contentTxt)
        view.addSubview(bottomBtn)


        navbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        navbar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        navbar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        navbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        contentTxt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        contentTxt.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentTxt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        contentTxt.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        bottomBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant:-10).isActive = true
        bottomBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        bottomBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func addConnectView(){
        print("addConnectView")

        self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
        let connect:connectView = {
            let content = connectView()
            content.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            return content
        }()
        connect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(connect)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: connect)
        connect.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        connect.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        connect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        connect.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    @objc func addTemplateView(){
        print("addTemplateView")
        self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
        let content:templateView = {
            let content = templateView()
            content.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            return content
        }()

        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(content)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: content)
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    @objc func addSettingView(){
        print("addSettingView")
        self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
        let content:settingView = {
            let content = settingView()
            content.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            return content
        }()

        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(content)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: content)
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    @objc func addAchievementView(){
        print("addAchievementView")
        self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
        let content:achievementView = {
            let content = achievementView()
            content.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            return content
        }()

        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(content)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: content)
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    @objc func addCommandView(){
        print("addCommandView")
        self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
        let content:commandView = {
            let content = commandView()
            content.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
            return content
        }()

        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(content)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: content)
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    @objc func addListView(){
        print("addListView")
        self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
        let content:commandView = {
            let content = commandView()
            content.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            return content
        }()

        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(content)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: content)
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    @objc func addNavbarView(){
        print("addNavbarView")
        self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
        let content:navbarListView = {
            let content = navbarListView()
            content.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            return content
        }()

        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(content)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: content)
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func sideController(){
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sideViewController") as! sideViewController
        self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func profileController(){
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! profileViewController
        self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before add any view make sure to remove all other , as you don't know what is currently displayed so

```
 self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
 self.content.removeFromSuperview()   //
 self.content.removeFromSuperview() // for settings
```

Also this line is the problem

```
self.view.sendSubview(toBack: content)
```

as by default the added view is placed above all childs of the parentView

I vote for creating `placeHolderView` and remove it's subviews before any addition , this will prevent headache of knowing which one is currently displayed , or you may give a tag to any added view and do this before any new addition

```
self.view.subviews.forEach { if $0.tag == 11 {
  $0.removeFromSuperview()
}}
```

Comment: what is $0.tag == 11, mean why number 11?

Comment: any number other than 0 as it's the default tag for any view